# Text selection from mouse does not work

Tags: swing, javafx, jxbrowser

I have a simple *Hello world* HTML page displayed using a JxBrowser embedded on a **JavaFX** component. I am using the *Lightweight accelerated* mode ([lightweight_accelerated](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000104965-accelerated-lightweight-rendering))

Code looks like this :

```
FXCanvas fxComposite = new FXCanvas(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
Browser browser = new Browser(BrowserType.LIGHTWEIGHT);
com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.javafx.BrowserView view = new com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.javafx.BrowserView(
                browser);
fxComposite.setScene(FXResourceManager.createScene(view));
browser.setHtml("<p>Hello <span>World!</span></p>");
```

Text selection works fine when using *CTRL + A* shortcut or when a word is double-clicked, but it does not when I try to do a "mouse selection" (e.g. selecting "Hell").

I found out that it does work if I switch to HEAVYWEIGHT mode or if I use SWING component instead.

Is there a way to make it work with both JavaFx component and LIGHTWEIGHT (accelerated mode)?

Comment: I'm sure you have a reason for using JxBrowser and have already looked at this, but JavaFX has a [WebView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) component for HTML display, why not just use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it has nothing to do with JxBrowser. This behaviour is caused by a known JavaFx bug : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8096818

It has been fixed in version 8u60 (released in 2015).